# Page Break on Change of Column Value

Tags: reporting-services

I have a simple customer history report that has the following elements:
Header that contains the customer name and customer ID pulled from 1 of 2 datasets

Rectangle that contains a list which provides some details order items like date ordered date shipped invoice number and such.

Sub report placed within the list area that contains table with order details.

This report functions fine if I call one customer at a time.  I need to print multiple customers at a time so I have multiple values for my parameter.  When I try to call more then one customer I get the following results:

The header prints with the first customer data and shows it on all pages.  The list renders as designed but pulls all customers data so it appears there is just one customer.

What I need is a page break for each customer.  When I new page starts I need the customer name to be shown on all of the pages that group will print.  Placing the name at the top of the first page only does not work for my situation. I have tried placing pages breaks after the list.  I have placed page breaks after the containing rectangle and I have created another rectangle and nested the original rectangle within this new parent with a page break on the new parent but none of these will work.  I have also tried placing the customer info in the header but all I get is the information from the first record in the dataset.

This seems like a simple report but I just cannot seem to get the page break to fire when the customer ID changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSRS page break after row with subreport (in rectangle)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27618159/ssrs-page-break-after-row-with-subreport-in-rectangle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by using the information at these 2 sites

[Solved the problem of getting the page to break after the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257276/how-to-create-a-report-with-sections-and-page-breaks-using-ssrs)

This allowed me to have a page break for each customer.  It placed another row in the tablix that contained the group on field, which in my case was the name.  I had to make a modification to hide this new row so I changed it's width to a very small space and set it property to hidden.  I then placed a text box above my list to show the name there.

[Solved name at top of every page in the group](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/38c1a7d3-f2db-4ed5-9287-34da112031ce/show-sum-total-on-every-page?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Answer (score 0):

In the properties of your `List` object, go to `PageBreak`, and set `BreakLocation` to "End".

Make sure `Disabled` is set to "False".

Comment: Your list is using a Dataset that returns one row per customer?

Comment: No the list will return multiple rows per customer.  I have been able to get the page break to work using the solution from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257276/how-to-create-a-report-with-sections-and-page-breaks-using-ssrs  But the customer name only shows on the top of the first page after the break.  If the customer has multiple pages the name does not appear on those pages.  I need to have the name on the top of every page in the group